# Modify the SelectListItem getter to return a modified Text Value

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, selectlistitem

I have a class that has a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` as one of its properties. I'm using this list to populate a `@Html.DropDownListFor()` Drop down list - this is working and I am getting the values I expect in my dropdown.

However I want to modify the text value that shows in the drop down list.

I think one way to do this would be to modify the value in the Getter something like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ShippingQuotes
    {
        get { return ShippingQuotes; }//SomethingHere to modify the text property of the Select List Items; 

        set { ShippingQuotes = value; }
    }
```

Can someone help me with the syntax here?

Comment: Look closely at the `SelectListItem` constructors and use the one which suits your needs. It's very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply modify its text using `Select()`:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ShippingQuotes
{
     get { return shippingQuotes.Select(x => {x.Text = "Some Text" + x.Text; return x;}); } 
     set { ShippingQuotes = value; }
}
```

Comment: I see what you're doing. It's never a good idea to do modifications in a `Select`. It should be used for querying and not editing.

Comment: I Disagree, if we were just querying, we would use `Where`, `Select` is used for mapping and modification

Comment: It violates the principles of functional programming because it has side effects. You can continue doing it but I just wanted to let you know. Now you know.

Comment: Actually when I did this for some reason, it just kept crashing at run time. BUT.... the syntax was right, I just applied it after I get the value out rather than in the getter, works thanks, marking this as correct as its what I needed.

Comment: @AyoAdesina I'm glad I could help.